# Inner Product Notation

Tags: geometry, inner-products

I'm using a mathematics research paper to write code that calculates the minimum distance between two polygons. While I understand this isn't a code site, my questions is focused on how to read mathematical notation.

How do I interpert `the angle between a point1 and line segment m = s(point2, point3)` ? And the converse the `the angle between line segment m = s(point2, point3)and a point1`?

The values should range form **-2*PI to 2*Pi**

I'm first defining the **angle_between(point1, point2, point3):**

```
atan2(point3.y - point2.y, point3.x - point2.x) - atan2(point2.y - point1.y, point2.x - point1.x
```

1. So in this paper, is alpha_double_prime:

   `angle_between(m(p), m(q),e(i)) OR the opposite angle_between(m(q), m(p),e(i))`
2. In this paper, is beta_double_prime equal to:

   `angle_between(m(p), m(q),f(j-1)) OR the opposite angle_between(m(q), m(p),f(j-1))`

[image: Paragraph]

[image: Polygon]

[Paper referenced](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8ghirphu3m83u4/1-s2.0-0196677485900392-main%20%283%29.pdf?dl=0)